# Remove header in fancyhdr with new sections

Tags: lyx, fancyhdr, article

I'm writing my thesis in LyX with the article class.

I want my headers to have the "Section X. " except for the pages where the new sections start. Is there any way to do this?

My current code is as follows. My issue is two fold:
1) I can't remove the header on the Section pages
2) When I get into subsections (i.e. 2.2 or something) it prints this, rather than the "Section 2. ".

On a side note: I just used the article class since this is what I've used before. Is this a bad idea for a big project? Layout wise it's fine so far (i.e. I don't want a book layout or similar).

```
\fancyhf{}               % Clear fancy header/footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\chaptername\  \thesection.\ #1}}

\lhead{\rightmark}   % My name in Left header
```

Comment: Try to add ``\thispagestyle{empty}`` after section or define own page style and use ti instead ``plain``

Comment: For a thesis is better book, scrbook (KOMA-script book),  memoir, Tufte bok, or .... some of the several class and templates for thesis (http://www.ctan.org/topic/dissertation) but in plain LaTeX (without using Lyx, except if you know how to make lyx layouts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it with the following and then use \thispagestyle{plain} on the Section pages to retain page numbers but remove headers:

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername \ \thesection. #1}{}}
\lhead{\leftmark}
```